# use zip command in linux bash

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am currently doing an exercise on bash. Trying to use bzip2 gzip and zip to determine which way is most efficient compressing program. The question is on the zip command part. It works and echo the size of file ziped. However, the linux shows that

```
line 22: adding:: command not found
```

[image]

Comment: Please copy and paste your code into your question. [Don't screenshot it](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/100397). You do that and I can copy/paste it to give you a reason for the problem

Answer (score 4):

The error comes from your use of `$()`:

```
$(zip "$1.zip" $1)
```

This is [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html), which replaces the command with its output. So the shell takes `zip`’s output and tries to interpret it as part of the shell script:

```
adding: ...
```

`adding:` isn’t a valid command on your system, and the shell complains about it.

You should run the command directly:

```
zip "$1.zip" "$1"
```

If you want to get rid of its output, redirect it, or use `zip`’s `-q` option (“quiet”):

```
zip "$1.zip" "$1" > /dev/null
zip -q "$1.zip" "$1"
```

This will still show any errors that occur.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the zip command installed. I'm on Debian Linux, and zip is not installed by default, even though unzip is installed.

Also, the syntax for the command calling zip is different than the commands calling gzip and bzip2:

```
"$1.zip" versus "${1}.bz2" and "${1}.gz"
```

Comment: i did have zip command installed.

Comment: Hmm. Then I wonder if it is because you left out the {} in "$1.zip", while you have "${1}.bz2" and "${1}.gz".

Comment: `$1` is no different to `${1}`